# mouse problems after nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=4

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, gpu, fancontrol

```
nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus
nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=4
```

from [forums.developer.nvidia.com](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/adjust-nvidia-gpu-fan-speed-multiple-gpus-one-monitor/49241/3) worked with my dual titan rtx on Ubuntu 18. This allows me to manually set the fan speed using NVIDIA X Server Setting.  Otherwise, the GPU runs real hot during training (86C).  When I set fans to 100%, the temperature is at 66C during training.

Upgraded to ubuntu 20.04, everything very stable except after setting the `coolbits=4`. When I do, I get manual fan control, but after the screen times out and darkens, I log in, the mouse does not appear. reboot using the `<CTRL><ALT>T` to get a terminal(no mouse), `sudo reboot`, log in and all is fine until the screen darkens after a timeout.

Delete the /etc/X11/xorg.config, reboot, then all is good again, even after screen times out and darkens, but no GPU fan speed control.

Very repeatable.

Any other way to enable manual fan speed control on NVIDIA?

I tried sudo `nvidia-smi --gpu-target-temp=70` but this had no effect on fan speed.

The **/etc/X11/xorg.config** created by **nvidia-xconfig**

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 460.32.03


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "TITAN RTX"
    BusID          "PCI:33:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "TITAN RTX"
    BusID          "PCI:74:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Coolbits" "4"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Coolbits" "4"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: USB mouse? If you replug it after the "screen dims" (which I assume is a sleep state) does the mouse come back (watch dmesg/syslog to see the USB event? Might be power saving on the mouse/system??

Comment: I tried to unplug, replug even in a new position. no difference. will try dmesg/syslog